# What's the definition of 'edit' on the user->editors page?

Tags: discussion, edits, users-page, edit-badges

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors

What exactly counts as an edit here? I ask because apparently I have made 765 edits, but I don't have the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badge (edited 500 posts), so it seems `edits != n edited posts`.

Comment: [Here][1] few more details are added, which can clarify more.


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing

Answer (score 4):

The Copy Editor badge (and related badges) do not count edits you made to your own posts.