# Strunk & White badge missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, edits

According, to [the user tab on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all), both Fabian and I have edited over 80 posts. By that logic, both he and I should have our Strunk & White badge, but it's missing for us both.

Ivo Flipse [is also missing the badge](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) on Fitness & Nutrition.

Comment: may be a little bit related with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81645/userstab-editors-puts-paid-to-editor-category-badge-queries-on-data-explorer

Comment: I had the same question some time ago. You've got more helpful responses though: [What's the definition of edit on the user->editors page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82096/whats-the-definition-of-edit-on-the-user-editors-page)

Comment: I too had the same question... and it s solved!!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The users page tab for editors lists all edits, including edits to your own posts and retags. Strunk & White only cares about body and title edits to other users' posts.

Unless you avoid all forms of editing that do not qualify for Strunk & White, that page will not accurately measure your progress towards the badge. I'll quote [the Badge requirements list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) for your convenience:

> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to CW posts **do** count
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> - Tag wiki edits **do** count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved

Comment: Ah. That makes sense (though, very confusing).

Comment: Grr, very annoying. I just got to 80, but most of my earliest edits are of my own questions and answers.

Comment: @Grace Note Is there a way to exclude edits which do not count from the total edits I made?

Comment: @banarun If you go to a review queue and hover over the bar showing your review progress it will show you your progress towards "copy editor."

Answer (score 9):

See my answer to [How do I know how many posts I've edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7997/how-do-i-know-how-many-posts-ive-edited/84489#84489) for the best way to see your accurate edits.  That users tab seems to show all edits - even to your own posts (mine says 244 on Programmers, while the query says 84, which is correct — I just earned my Strunk & White badge).