# More than 80 posts and no editor badge

Tags: support, edit-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strunk & White badge missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing)

According to the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white), all you need to get the Strunk & White badge is 80 edits.

I have [88](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=Jon) of them but still don't recieve it.

Something missing?

Comment: Same response as here: [Strunk & White badge missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing). To reiterate [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing/84767#84767), the editor tab lists all edits, not just the ones which qualify for the badge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do all edits conform to these rules?:

1. Perform a total of 80 edits between
   questions and answers
2. Edits on deleted posts **do not** count
3. Edits to your own posts **do not** count
4. Edits to CW posts **do** count
5. Edits that consist only of tag
   changes **do not** count
6. Tag wiki edits **do** count
7. Edits you suggest before gaining
   full edit privileges **do** count, **once
   approved**

Consult the [list of all badges and requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258).

Comment: I thought that the editor tab showed the edits that counted, not all of them. Thanks for the info!