# Strunk and White isn't counting all edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, badge-progress

Not sure what's going on here, but the numbers don't add up:

[image: Strunk & White badge progress]

If you can see the image, the badge progress shows me at 67 of 80, but the impact summary shows 337.

It's possible at lot of those edits are to my own posts (not sure if own-post edits qualify). It's also possible a lot of those edits are from before Stunk & White existed. Another option is that this is a problem with the new user page, rather than the badge, but I'm not in a position to see that.

If this is that first option, and edits to my own posts don't count, this is still a confusing situation, and a change to the text on that badge summary might be appropriate.

Comment: fwiw, I love the user profile summary. I would never have noticed or cared without it. Not that I really care all that much on meta any more anyway, but I'd had this to go to production if there's a bug.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84767/217361) for the full criteria.

Comment: That's probably it, then: I doubt I have many posts that I haven't gone back and edited at some point. My fingers tend to have a mind of their own when it comes to typing, and I don't have a copy-editor's brain. Still, this is a confusing view to find on the page. We might want to change some of the text.

Answer (score 5):

From [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244), [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) and [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor) badges require you to meet the following criteria regarding edits:

- Edits on deleted posts do not count
- Edits to your own posts do not count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Edits to community wiki posts **do** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/168244))
- Tag wiki edits **do** count ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442))
- Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76916/168244))
- Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

As such, total edits (or revisions) doesn't necessarily match requirements for the editor-related badges.