# Edit counts toward Strunk & White badge do not always add up to 80

Tags: support, edits, badges, data-explorer, edit-badges

There are a number of **similar** questions but they don't seem to capture the following: There is a list of criteria for edits that do / do not count towards the Strunk & White badge; however, when I write a [query on the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1025449) (addressing those criteria) I find the total number of edits per user does not always add up to 80 by the time that the Strunk & White badge is obtained. Does anyone know what is the cause of this discrepancy? It is possible that I am missing something in the query but I have tried to align it to the list of criteria as much as possible.

**Notes:**

1. More often than not, the above query under counts the number of edits per user (but this is not a hard rule - sometimes it over counts).
2. The criteria for edits that count are found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251680/505284
3. Other query examples can be found here: [Strunk-and-White problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem). However, these examples don't necessarily include some of the inclusions (so I expect they will get to an even lower number per user than the link I have provided above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a reason why your query reports numbers lower than 80 (but not for the numbers higher than 80). A user might (correctly) receive a Strunk & White badge for 80 edits, but later on, some posts they edited are deleted. They keep the badge, but almost all information about deleted posts is not included in SEDE. Therefore, your query thinks they've made less edits.

---

FWIW, I have a [Global Edit Summary](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/867123/global-edit-summary) which is (on some sites) off by one or more posts (but pretty accurate overall). It is similar to your query, except that it considers only PostHistory entries of type 4 and 5; you would expect 1 and 2 to be necessary for tag wikis/excerpts, but those are created by the Community user and then edited (type 5) by the first contributor.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense regarding the deleted posts. I had hoped that the post history would remain even if the post was deleted (otherwise I would have included an `inner join` rather than that `not in` term) but maybe that was too hopeful. Do you have any idea where I can get at the deleted posts? Or is that simply not available data?

Comment: The PostHistoryType in (1,2) might account for a small part of the over counting. I will check up on that.

Comment: That data is simply not available (see the [schema / documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232)). I've removed the part about my Travel.Meta profile, I'll probably turn that into another question since it's not related to your question.

Comment: Okay excellent. Thanks very much again. I still cant get to the bottom of the over-count issue but that is far less prominent. So I'll put the bulk of the mis-counting down to the under-counting which must be due to deleted posts.