# Posts edited counter (for Strunk & White badge) is sometimes off

Tags: bug, status-review, edits, badge-progress, edit-badges

This question is inspired by [Edit counts toward Strunk & White badge do not always add up to 80](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326502), where I remembered that I wrote a [Global Edit Summary](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/867123/global-edit-summary?AccountId=6085540), which is (on some sites) off by one or more posts.

As an example, consider my [Lifehacks Meta profile](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5345/glorfindel?tab=summary). The SEDE query says 14 posts edited, but the profile and the badge tracker say 20:

[image]

There are [20 revisions listed](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5345/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=revisions), but six posts were edited twice, as [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/lifehacksme/query/1706426?UserId=5345) shows:

[image]

Edits to deleted posts [don't count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251680/295232), so in theory everything *should* be visible on the profile, right? Or am I missing something here?

Most of the times, the query produces the same results as the counter on my profile (not counting edits made after last Sunday morning) but there are a few other sites where the counter and/or the query are off (e.g. Bitcoin where the query reports 54 and the profile 55).

I've found another case where the counter is off by a wide margin. On Board & Card Games, my profile claims I've edited 867 posts, while the [appropriate SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/boardgames/query/1161635/local-edit-summary?UserId=12315) says I edited only 781 – 86 less. It wouldn't fully explain the difference, but I've done almost 50 tag-only edits. They are not supposed to count towards the badge, but maybe they do?

Comment: Unlike the Strunk & White badge itself, which only counts each post once, the posts edited count in your impact box *does* count posts more than once. The query actually counts distinct RevisionGUIDs rather than distinct PostIds, which means multiple revisions to the same post are counted separately. I'm almost certain that's not intended, because that would make little sense labeled as "posts edited" which implies a count of posts, not a count of revisions. It even contradicts the very name of the method: GetDistinctPostsEdited

Comment: Hmm ... the Strunk & White badge tracker also says 10 posts edited (same root cause maybe). Well, then it's probably a real [bug].

Comment: Just checked, it does. Doesn't use the same method, weirdly, and there are other small tweaks to the query which make it do the same thing, but it is definitely counting RevisionGUIDs instead of PostIds.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, please re-add the [status-review] tag, along with any updated context that might be relevant to reproduce it.

Comment: @JNat I found a better example, where the counter does not seem to look for *unique* post IDs but simply counts all revisions.